# Resolve 'Equations for ‘cycleNext’ have different numbers of arguments'

Tags: haskell

Any ideas how to resolve the error `Equations for ‘cycleNext’ have different numbers of arguments` without adding redundant argument to the last line?

```
cycleNext :: (Eq a, Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
cycleNext maxBound = minBound
cycleNext = succ
```

Comment: I don't see any way you can. (You can rewrite the function in a number of ways but all involve specifying an argument to the function.) I'm not sure why it's such a problem though, sure "pointfree" style is nice but there's no great loss here in making the last line `cycleNext x = succ x`

Comment: I'm just trying to deal with HLint warn `Pattern match is redundant` that happens on `cycleNext x = succ x`

Comment: @ArkadyRost: that is because `maxBound` is treated as a variable, not as the `maxBound` *value*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oops, not sure how I didn't spot that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, the number of parameters should be the same. Note that your `maxBound` will *not* work. Indeed, `maxBound` starts with a lowercase, and is thus treated as a variable (if you turn on warnings, it will warn that `maxBound` is shadowing an existing binding).

You thus can implement this with:

```
cycleNext :: (Eq a, Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
cycleNext x | x == maxBound = minBound
            | otherwise = succ x
```